# How to change the pop-up position of jQuery datetimepicker by xdan on below/above the textbox dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, datetimepicker

I am using this plugin on my code.

```
<script language="Javascript" src="/MyJs 
/js/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="MyCss
/css/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>
```

How can the position on Pop up of the datetimepicker be changed dynamically?

e.g.

1. When I am at the bottom of the page the datetimepicker should come at the top of the textbox.
2. When I am at the top of the page the datetimepicker should come at the just at the bottom of the textbox.